# How to choose semi-pro MTB for all weather

Tags: mountain-bike, weather, rain, city

I'm looking for universal semi-pro quality MTB for all weather.

I'd like to have mounts for installation of sturdy metallic mudguards.
Example:
[image]

Also I'd like to have option to install confortable seat like:
[image]

---

Currently I'm considering two options:

**Merida BIG.NINE 100-2x 29"**

https://www.merida-bikes.com/fi-fi/bike/3041/bignine-100-2x
[image]
Available for 750 EUR

---

**Romet MUSTANG M5 29" (2022)**

https://www.romet.pl/Rower,MUSTANG_M5,10,812,15629,2022.html#00008BC0C0C0-17

https://www.cyclesolutions.co.uk/bikes/mountain-bikes/romet-mustang-m5-2021-29er-hardtail-mountain-bike--blackdark-gold--19-inch__84956

[image]
Available for 700 EUR

Any advice from experience what to look for so I can get best sturdy mudguards?
What are other important things I should I pay attention when selecting bike?

What bike is the best value for money?

Comment: I voted to close because shopping questions are off topic.  However I can definitely say you won't be getting semi-pro quality on that budget.

Comment: Consider joining [chat] instead - this is a shopping question.  And theres a lot of sub-questions in here.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to put mudguards to my first E bike but I went through three iterations before getting them right. There are no mounting points where expected, they do not fit, they do not cover well. At the same time, versions with fenders already fitted cost near the same.

Hence if you do plan all weather riding, I suggest buying a bicycle with serious mudguards pre installed.